# Ayuda con contar y comparar una variable en FOR en C

Tags: c, variables, loops

espero que me puedan ayudar con este enunciado que me dieron de tarea, no le encuentro la forma de hacer el punto a, y con el resto:

-Como resultado de un experimento un laboratorio obtuvo 18 valores
de temperatura, todos distintos de cero. Se debe realizar un programa
para ingresar dichos valores y luego determinar e informar:

a) La mayor temperatura ingresada y cual fue su número de 
    orden durante el ingreso.

b) Ídem para la menor temperatura.

c) El promedio de las temperaturas negativas. Si no hubiera 
    temperaturas negativas indicarlo con un cartel aclaratorio.

Esto es lo que llegue a hacer:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a, i, max, min;
int main( void ) {
  for (i=0;i<18;i++) {
    printf(" Introduzca el valor de temperatura: \n");
    scanf("%d", &a);

    if(i==0){
      max=a;
      min=a;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Está hecho *a la cabeza* pero, salvo cambios mínimos, debería funcionar.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int max = 0, maxIdx; // Máximas.
int min = 0, minIdx; // Mínimas.
int negAcu = 0, negCount = 0; // Negativas.

int main( void ) {
  int curr;

  for( i = 0; i < 18; ++i ) {
    printf(" Introduzca el valor de temperatura: \n");
    scanf( "%d", curr );

    if( curr > max ) {
      max = curr;
      maxIdx = i;
    }

    if( curr < min ) {
      min = curr;
      minIdx = i;
    }

    if( curr < 0 ) {
      negAcu += curr;
      ++negCount;
    }
  }

  printf( "Temperatura máxima: %d; orden: %d\n", max, maxIdx );
  printf( "Temperatura mínima: %d; orden: %d\n", min, minIdx );

  if( negCount ) {
    printf( "Promedio de temperaturas negativas: %d\n", negAcu / negCount );
  } else {
    printf( "SIN temperaturas negativas.\n" );
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Espero que compartas la nota de la asignatura con el resto de usuarios, porque eso es, prácticamente, el ejercicio **entero** ;-)

Comment: Si, muchas gracias, la verdad es que me pongo a analizar el codigo para ver como lo hizo funcionar, asi que también me ayuda mucho a entender.